# How to achive this query in Eloquent to show the results in a table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to show some info about the last registrations in a conference in a table like below. This tables shows, for example, that the last registration was did by John and is a registration with 2 participants and the total value of the registration was 10.00.

```
User that did the registration | Quantity of participants registered | Total Value
            John                               2                        10.00$
            Jake                               1                        5.00$
```

I have this query that shows the above result:

```php
SELECT users.name,COUNT(participants.registration_id),SUM(registration_types.price) 
FROM participants
INNER JOIN registration_types 
        on participants.registration_type_id =
          registration_types.id
INNER JOIN registrations
        on registrations.registration_id =
           participants.registration_id
INNER JOIN users
        on users.id = registrations.user_that_did_registration
group by users.name
```

But I want to use Eloquent to do the query so then is possible to show the results in a foreah in the table:

```php
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm box-shaddow">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">User that did registration</th>
        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With Eloquent I have like below but its not working. Do you know how the query should be so is possible to show the necessary data in the table?

```php
$registrationsInfo = Participant::
    leftJoin('registration_types', 'participants.registration_type_id', '=', 'registration_types.id')
->leftJoin('registrations', 'registration.id', '=', 'participants.registration_id')
->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'registrations.user_that_did_registration')
->selectRaw('users.name, count(participants.registration_id), sum(registration_types.price)')
->groupBy('users.name')
->get();
```

**Relevant models for the question:**

Users model:

```php
public function registrations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Registration','user_that_did_registration');
}
```

Registration model:

```php
// user that did the registration
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_that_did_registration', 'id');
}
 public function participants(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
}

public function conference(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
}
```

Conference Model:

```php
 public function registrations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'conference_id');
}
```

Participants mode:

```php
public function registration(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
}

public function registration_type(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\RegistrationType');
}
```

Registration Type model:

```php
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }


    public function participants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
    }

    public function registrations(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Registration', 'registration_registration_types');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$registrations = DB::table('registrations')
        ->join('participants', 'registrations.id', '=', 'participants.registration_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'registrations. user_that_did_registration_id')
        ->join('registration_types', 'registration_types.id', '=', 'participants.registration_type_id')
        ->select( DB::raw('count(participants.registration_id) as participants_count, sum(registration_types.price) as totalPrice, users.name as userName'))
        ->groupBy('users.name')->get();
```

Loop it like this

```
foreach($registrations as $registration){
    echo $registration->userName." - ".$registration->participants_count." - ". $registration->totalPrice;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it appears "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'project.users.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in (1, 2) group by `name`)".

Comment: Is necessary a ";" after "$query->groupBy('name')"?

Comment: yes that necessary, but error saying something else

Comment: In the error it appears also ""SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.name' in 'group statement' (SQL: select `registrations`.*, (select count(*) from `participants` where `registrations`.`id` = `participants`.`registration_id`) as `participants_count` from `registrations` group by `users`.`name`) ◀".

Comment: don't you have `name` field in users table ?

Comment: Yes, the users table has the name field.

Comment: @John i have update answer with now using Query builder. try it

Comment: Thanks now the query dont shows any error. But to show the results in the table appears "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$participants_count", "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$userName", "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$totalPrice".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173830/discussion-between-rkj-and-john).